# Expresión (regex) que tome 2 dígitos asemejando input de mes

Tags: javascript, html5, regex

Se necesita es que el usuario ingrese El mes en Numero (sin usar ningún control de fecha); donde debe validar que sea un numero positivo y que acepte 1 al 9  y 0 al 2; solo que **No** requieren que se coloque mes 01 o mes 09 si no 9 o 1; Lo que he realizado hasta el momento es esto

```
^[+]?(0[1-9]|1[0-2])
```

El problema es que este debe usar el mes 01 y es lo que no quiere el usuario.

```js
var re = /^[+]?(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/;

console.log(re.test('') + ' No cumple' ); 
console.log(re.test('1')+ ' No cumple deberia Cumplir'); 
console.log(re.test('01'));
console.log(re.test('12'));
console.log(re.test('13') + ' No cumple');
console.log(re.test('9') + ' No cumple deberia Cumplir');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con `/^[+]?(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])$/`

He puesto que el cero sea opcional `0?`, y también he puesto que la cadena tiene que acabar allí `$`.

No sé si esta última condición te vale, pero si no la pongo, acepta también el 13 (en realidad se queda con el 1, el 3 no pasa la condición, pero al pasar parte de la cadena de texto la da por válida).

Si no pones `$`, de hecho, también te dará por válidos: 22, 45, 023, etc.

```js
var re = /^[+]?(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])$/;

console.log(re.test('') + ' debería fallar' ); 
console.log(re.test('1') + ' debería cumplir'); 
console.log(re.test('01') + ' debería cumplir');
console.log(re.test('12') + ' debería cumplir');
console.log(re.test('13') + ' debería fallar');
console.log(re.test('9') + ' debería cumplir');
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías lograrlo así:

- Agregar `?` al `0` (cero) en el grupo para los meses menores a `10`
- Agregar `$` al final de la expresión regular, para validar la cadena completa
- **OPCIONAL**: sacar `[+]?` (*personalmente,no sabría para que esta*)

#### Demo:

```js
var re = /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])$/;

console.log(re.test('') + ' No cumple' ); 
console.log(re.test('1')+ ' No cumple deberia Cumplir'); 
console.log(re.test('01'));
console.log(re.test('12'));
console.log(re.test('13') + ' No cumple');
console.log(re.test('9') + ' No cumple deberia Cumplir');
```

Comment: [+] es para que sean numero positivos, se debe ingresar solo positivos

Comment: @ger, normalmente los números positivos no llevan `+`, entiendo que en la `RegExp` estaba opcional, pero si no tiene `+` no significa que sea negativo. Parece redundante, por lo puse como paso opcional.